# RSyslog does not work with a log file located outside of /var/log

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am unable to get rsyslog to write to a log file located in a directory other than /var/log.

The server is RHELS 5.6 and for the most part with a default configuration.  Other than the rsyslog specific changes (rules added to iptables, etc.)

It WORKS if I specify the following in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

`local6.*                 /var/log/MyLog.log`

However, it DOES NOT WORK if I were to create a log file at the location /Testing/MyLog.log, chmod -R 777 on it, and then update the configuration to:

`local6.*                 /Testing/MyLog.log`

I'm baffled because I set /Testing/MyLog.log (and the directory) with chown and chmod to have identical user:group and permissions as the log /var/log/MyLog.log (according to the output of ls -la).

What am I doing wrong?  Is this even possible?  I've even tried making a symbolic link in /var/log, nothing I've tried seems to work.  I've played around with all sorts of configuration options documented on the rsyslog website.

Comment: what distro are you using?

Comment: Redhat Enterprise Linux Server 5.6

Comment: It's selinux. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/semanage and there the File contexts example. Instead of httpd_sys_content_t you're probably want the var_log_t context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SELinux will prevent processes that are labeled `syslogd_t` to write to files that are (probably) labeled `default_t`. You need to label the file with something `syslogd_t` can write to. Files in `/var/log` are mostly labeled `var_log_t`, a type `syslogd_t` can surely write to.

You should **not** just relabel the files in `/Testing` to `var_log_t`, because that's bound to break at some point, when somebody executes an autorelabel at the next boot or runs `restorecon -FvR /`.

Instead, write a little policy that automatically and consistently labels your files in `/Testing`. Something to get your started. Your policy file could look similar to this:

```
/Testing(/.*)?    --    gen_context(system_u:object_r:var_log_t)
```

SELinux policy writing however, is a tad tricky. Which is why you should put stuff at the default location for that stuff.

However, I personally feel that logging should really go into `/var/log`. It's there for a reason. No matter how good you think your reason is for writing to `/Testing`, it's probably better to write to something like `/var/log/testing`.

Edit: no, no, no, no, no. That won't do. That was silly. You do not want to write a policy to allow `syslogd_t` to write to `var_log_t`, because that is already allowed by the default policy. You need to write filecontext rules (a .fc file), like my new snippet above, to label `/Testing` as `var_log_t` if you must...

Answer (score 0):

selinux is then stopping you from writing logs outside of /var/log. You can **test** it by turning it off **temporary**

```
setenforce 0
```

Then it should start writing to that new log directory.

Comment: And then people never turn it on again, which is a shame, because SELinux is a **great** security feature...